# Error while connecting microsoft CCF services from different domain

Tags: .net, wcf, web-services, security

I am getting the below error while I am accessing CCF services from the server side:

LSN0100: Error encountered while attempting to access the configuration web service. (Remove the "ConfigurationArea" AppSettings key to disable.)

**Stack Trace:**

at Microsoft.Ccf.Common.Listeners.Configuration.ListenerConfiguration.Initialize()
   at Microsoft.Ccf.Common.Listeners.Configuration.ListenerConfiguration.GetConfig(String sectionName)
   at Microsoft.Ccf.Common.Logging.Logging.Initialize()
   at Microsoft.Ccf.Common.Logging.Logging.TryInitialize()
   at Microsoft.Ccf.Common.Logging.Logging.Information(String appName, String message)

### at Unity.Ui.MainDesktop.Program.Main() in Program.cs:line 77

Inner Exception:
{"The HTTP request is unauthorized with client authentication scheme 'Ntlm'. The authentication header received from the server was 'Negotiate,NTLM'."}

**Inner Stack Trace:**

Server stack trace: 
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelUtilities.ValidateAuthentication(HttpWebRequest request, HttpWebResponse response, WebException responseException, HttpChannelFactory factory)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelUtilities.ValidateRequestReplyResponse(HttpWebRequest request, HttpWebResponse response, HttpChannelFactory factory, WebException responseException, ChannelBinding channelBinding)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelRequest.WaitForReply(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.RequestChannel.Request(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.RequestChannelBinder.Request(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage message)

Exception rethrown at [0]: 
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)
   at Microsoft.Ccf.Common.ConfigurationService.Configuration.GetConfigurations(GeneralFunctionsConfigurationType type, String area)
   at Microsoft.Ccf.Common.ConfigurationService.ConfigurationClient.GetConfigurations(GeneralFunctionsConfigurationType type, String area)
   at Microsoft.Ccf.Common.Listeners.Configuration.ListenerConfiguration.Initialize()

---

My services (including CCF services) are installed on a server which is in the different domain.While I am accesing those services from my client machine which is another domain I am getting the error :

**LSN0100: Error encountered while attempting to access the configuration web service. (Remove the "ConfigurationArea" AppSettings key to disable.)**

Note: From development environment(where services are installed) to development machine I am not facing any problem.But when I am accessing the services from development environment to production environment I am getting the issue.

Thanks